# Numpy: Duplicate mask for an array (returning True if we've seen that value before, False otherwise)

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm looking for a vectorized function that returns a mask with values of True if the value in the array has been seen before and False otherwise.

I'm looking for the fastest solution possible as speed is very important.

For example this is what I would like to see:

```
array = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
mask = [False, False, True, True, False]
```

So `is_duplicate = array[mask]` should return `[1, 2]`.

Is there a fast, vectorized way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: is the end goal getting `[1, 2]` or are you specifically interested in `[False, False, True, True, False]`?

Comment: The goal is actually for deduping! But I have an array in which I need to dedupe within sections of the array. For example, my array can be `array = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]` in which i may need to dedupe `array[0:4]` and `array[4:6]` to get `[1, 2, 1, 2]`. That's why I'm looking to build a mask, but happy to look into other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** With sorting

```
def mask_firstocc(a):
    sidx = a.argsort(kind='stable')
    b = a[sidx]
    out = np.r_[False,b[:-1] == b[1:]][sidx.argsort()]
    return out
```

We can use `array-assignment` to boost perf. further -

```
def mask_firstocc_v2(a):
    sidx = a.argsort(kind='stable')
    b = a[sidx]
    mask = np.r_[False,b[:-1] == b[1:]]
    out = np.empty(len(a), dtype=bool)
    out[sidx] = mask
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [166]: a
Out[166]: array([2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3])

In [167]: mask_firstocc(a)
Out[167]: array([False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False])
```

**Approach #2 :** With `np.unique(..., return_index)`

We can leverage `np.unique` with its `return_index` which seems to return the first occurence of each unique elemnent, hence a simple array-assignment and then indexing works -

```
def mask_firstocc_with_unique(a):
    mask = np.ones(len(a), dtype=bool)
    mask[np.unique(a, return_index=True)[1]] = False
    return mask
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually edited my question a bit, I'm looking for a numpy solution above all, because this package doesn't have pandas as a requirement, only numpy and scipy. Is there something similar in numpy? Thanks!

Comment: This is great, I used your mask_firstocc_v2, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.unique`

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2, 3])
_, ix = np.unique(a, return_index=True)
b = np.full(a.shape, True)
b[ix] = False

In [45]: b
Out[45]: array([False, False,  True,  True, False])
```

Comment: Runtime numbers are similar between unique and the argsort. Think unique sorts too.

Comment: This works altho unique seems a bit slower, and sorting works better for my use case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the `enumerate` method - which lets you loop through using `index + value` :

```
array = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]

mask = []

for i,v in enumerate(array):
  if array.index(v) == i:
    mask.append(False)
  else:
    mask.append(True)


print(mask)
```

Output:

```
[False, False, True, True, False]
```

Answer (score -1):

Almost by definition, this can't be vectorized.  The value of mask for any `index` depends on the value of `array` for every value between 0 and `index`.  There may be some algorithm where you expand `array` into a NxN matrix and do fancy tests, but you're still going to have an O(n^2) algorithm.  The straightforward set algorithm is O(n log n).